# Show result of query with count

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a query with a count statement and I wanna show the result 
something like this

[image: something like this]

I have a file with name `functions.php` where I make the query in a (obviously) function.

those are my functions:

```
function conection($bd_config){
    try {
        $conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['database'], $bd_config['user'], $bd_config['pass']);
        return $conection;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function checksession(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header('Location: ' .  ROUTE. '/login.php');
    }
}

@$us = $_SESSION['USER'][0];

    function notification_count($conexion, $us){
        $count = $conection->prepare('SELECT * FROM postulate WHERE du = $us AND seen = 0');
        $count->execute();
        $total = $count->rowCount();
        $total = $count->fetchColumn();
        return $total;
    }
```

I have another file with name `lateral.php` where I "call" the function and the view of `latera.view.php`

`lateral.php`:

```
<?php session_start();
require 'extras/config.php';
include 'functions.php';

checksession();

$conection = conection($bd_config);

$quantity = notification_count($conection, $us);

require "views/lateral.php";
```

`lateral.view.php`:

```
<div class="block-section text-center ">
  <img src="images/<?php echo($_SESSION['user'][14])  ?>" class="img-rounded" alt="">
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <h4><a href="perfil.php"><?php echo($_SESSION['user'][3])  ?></a></h4>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="mensajes.php"> Messages </a></li>
    <li><a href="notificaciones.php"> Notifications<?php here is where I want the total of the query ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="cambio.php"> Change password</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
<!-- Block side right -->
```

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: @JapanGuy mi question is. how can i do to show the result of my query in the `<li>`

Comment: the code is in Portugese/Italian , not sure, It is very hard to understand the variable and function names. Instead of just copy pasting the code, explain what it does or translate the whole thing to english

Comment: let me translate for you, wait a sec

Comment: replacing `<?php here is where I want the total of the query ?>` with `<?=$quantity;?>` should work

Comment: nope, i just try that, and send me an error of undefined variable

Comment: I dont know what your file structure is. Are you requiring/including `lateral.view.php` in `lateral.php`?

Comment: Yes, i'm requiring on the `lateral.php` where at the same tome I require th `lateral.view.php`

Comment: @JapanGuy thanks for taking your time and help me finally I got what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

in the file of functions I need to make my query like this:

```
function notifications_count($conection, $us){
    $count= $conection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postul WHERE du = $us AND seen = 0");
    $count->execute();
    $number_notu = $count->fetchAll();
    return $number_notu;
}
```

then in the file of notifications.php where onlye I print code and make a require of the view(`HTML`) I need to put something like this:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extra/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

$conection = conection($bd_config);
if (!$conection) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

$postul= get_people($notu_config['post_notu'], $conection, $us);

if (!$postul) {
    $vacio = "<li>The aren't any notifications</li>";
}

$total_notu = notu_count($conection, $us);

require "views/notifications.php";
```

and in the view of notifications where I print only `HTML`  I need to make a `foreach`:

```
<div class="block-section text-center ">
  <img src="images/<?php echo($_SESSION['user'][14])  ?>" class="img-rounded" alt="">
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <h4><a href="profile.php"><?php echo($_SESSION['user'][3])  ?></a></h4>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="messages.php"> Messages</a></li>
    <?php foreach ($total_notu as $notu) : ?>
    <li><a href="notificaciones.php"> Notificaciones <span class="badge "><?php echo "$notu[0]"; ?></span></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <li><a href="change.php"> Change password</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
<!-- Block side right -->
```

I hope I can help someone ho are on the same troble like me :)

Comment: Thanks! For adding to the ever growing heap of example code that appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. (The code does make use a prepared statement, but it doesn't use bind parameter to supply values. Why bother with prepared statement if we're just going to include a potentially unsafe value in the SQL text?  (We are assuming the call to `notu_count` is a reference to the `notifications_count` function.)

Comment: @spencer7593 hmm well, i don't know if using `trim`, `stripslashes `and `htmlspecialchars `helps in something...

Comment: `trim`, `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` functions help "in something", but those functions are not appropriate for escaping potentially unsafe values incorporated into a SQL statement. [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) is an appropriate function. But again, if we used a *bind placeholder* in the SQL text of the prepared statement, we would use a call to the [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) function to supply the value, and we wouldn't need to be concerned with "escaping" the value.

Comment: Could you give me some advice to modify my code into a safety code?

Comment: Here's some advice... in the SQL query, replace this: "**`$us`**" with a question mark "**`?`**". And after the `prepare`, before the `execute`, add a line:  **`$count->bindValue(1, $us, PDO::PARAM_STR);`**  (The first argument identifies which question mark placeholder we're referring to, in this case the "first" one, The second argument is the value we want to supply for the placeholder. The third argument specifies the datatype.    http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understand perfectly